# Indecomposable group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

By denition, an indecomposable group $G$ is a nontrivial group that cannot be
expressed as the internal direct product of two proper normal subgroups (i.e : if $H,K< G$ such that $G\cong H\times K$ so $H=0$ or $K=0.$

My question is: it is true that a $p$-group is an indecomposable group ?

Comment: No, consider $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Thank you @DavidPeterson .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For any prime $\;p\;$ , $\;C_p\times C_p\;$ is a decomposable $\;p-$ group. It is true if the group's order is a prime.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true neither non-abelian $p$-groups nor abelian $p$-groups.

For instance, you can consider non-abelian case,  $D_4\times D_4$ and for abelian case, you can consider every elementary abelian group.